# How to add additional drivers to android stack

Tags: android, linux-kernel, android-source, android-library, android-framework

I need to customize the android source code to add another secondary display for the device (this is the requirement). Hence i need to integrate the secondary display's drivers into the android stack and also add some libraries to the android stack using which the secondary display can be controlled. The driver code is readily available, so i only need to integrate it with the android stack. As i have never worked with android source code i hardly have any idea about how to proceed. Also there is no tutorial available for any kind of guidance for the same.

So far with the help of this site I'm able to setup the environment using the instructions given here: http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html

I should perform the integration on jelly Bean, so have downloaded JB source code.

Now proceeding towards integration of the drivers i have no idea how to proceed. Please provide some tutorials or useful links to do so.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [SO compiling Android kernel](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=compiling+an+android+kernel), [google same](https://www.google.ca/#q=compile+android+kernel).  First hit [Building kernels](http://source.android.com/source/building-kernels.html).  The answer can be large and depends on whether you have an existing `.config` or not.  What have you tried?

Comment: @artlessnoise: First of all thanks for your reply, as i'm very much stuck at the same place. Now what i have is, i have a makefile which when run on a treminal generate *.so files that are the library files. And i have no idea about .config file as i have never dealt with it.

Comment: [Build module w/o kernel source](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/build-linux-kernel-module-against-installed-kernel-source-tree.html), [SO same](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10456628/build-a-linux-module-without-source-code), [module building doc](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt).  Android may have `/proc/config`; run `uname` from *adb* to get a kernel version.  You need to get the appropriate kernel headers from somewhere and then you should be able to follow some of the instructions.